# foreach can not get an enumerator of a struct element

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerator

I have a struct like this and I have an array `sorular[] soru`.

```
public struct sorular
{
   public string resim;
   public string soru;
   public string seceneka;
   public string secenekb;
   public string secenekc;
   public string secenekd;
   public int dogrucevap;
   public int verilencevap;
}
```

And I would like to use a `foreach` loop, like:

```
foreach (int i in sorular.dogrucevap)
{

}
```

But I can't do it because of the `cant get enumerator of dogrucevap` error. I don't want to use a `while` or `for` loop :)

Comment: It is a single field `public int dogrucevap;`, it is not a collection of `int`. You can't enumerate it.

Comment: What's wrong with `Foreach (sorular s in soru) { int i = s.dogrucevap; }` ?

Comment: @Brian: still won't work without implementing IEnumerable

Comment: @PierreOverFlow - `soru` is an array. It implements IEnumerable.

Comment: @TravisJ: I didn't see that first line of the question, yes you are very right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't iterate over something that is not a collection or otherwise iterable type.

Based on your updates, here is what I believe you are looking for:

```
foreach (sorular s in soru) {
    var i = s.dogrucevap;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thx Zachary What i needed to know is i have structure array :) Thx to everyone who helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `sorular.dogrucevap` in `foreach` statement, it should return object which has method `GetEnumerator` (or implement `IEnumerable` interface).

**Why you have *'cant get enumerator of dogrucevap'* error?**

Foreach statement enumerates the elements of a collection, executing an embedded statement for each element of the collection and its defined as (C# Specification 8.8.4 The foreach statement):

```
foreach (local-variable-type identifier in expression)
    embedded-statement
```

If *expression* in foreach statement is not an array or dynamic, then it should have appropriate `GetEnumerator` method which defined as:

> member on the type X with identifier GetEnumerator and
>   no type arguments.

In your case *expression* returns value of type `int`. Thus `int` does not have `GetEnumerator` method, it cannot be used in foreach statement. Actually it does not make any sense, because `int` does not look as collection. What items you are expecting to enumerate in integer value `42`?

**How to fix problem?** Assume you want to enumerate structs in your structs array. Then code should look like

```
 sorular[] soru;
 // intialize and fill array

 foreach(sorular s in soru)
 {
    // use s.dogrucevap
 }
```

Or if you want to enumerate `dogrucevap` values of structs in array, then you can [project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) array items by selecting only this value:

```
 foreach(int dogrucevap in soru.Select(s => s.dogrucevap))
 {
     // use dogrucevap
 }
```

Comment: The "sorular.dogrucevap" does not make any sense in the foreach loop, it is an integer type which is not an iterative type.

Answer (score 2):

> I have an array sorular[] soru.

Since have an array of these structs in soru, you can project out of them to get a set of the dogrucevap values.

```
IEnumerable<int> dogrucevaps = soru.Select(s => s.dogrucevap);
```

And then you may iterate these

```
foreach( int i in dogrucevaps )
{
   //TODO: use i
}
```

In condensed form

```
foreach(int i in soru.Select(s => s.dogrucevap))
{
   //TODO: use i    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your value is integer - you can't iterate integer directly.

If you just want `foreach` of single item - `Enumerable.Repeat` for single item to have one iteration:

```
foreach(int i in Enumerable.Repeat(questions.dogrucevap,1 ))
{

}
```

If you "dogrucevap" varialbe means something "from 1 to dogrucevap" you can construct `Range` out of it and `foreach` on the range:

```
foreach(int i in Enumerable.Range(1,questions.dogrucevap))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, instead of a struct you would be better off using a class.

As you are using an array `sorular[] soru`  then you can do the following:

```
foreach (var item in soru)
{
    // do something with item.dogrucevap which is an int
}
```

Alternately, if you want to iterate over the fields of the structure you can use reflection.

Comment: Worked thx didnt thought this retard brain of mine :) i will look for reflection too  thx for giving answer :)

Comment: If you are able to accept this as an answer it would be helpful.